# android java building a simple window with title, body and button

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to create a simple activity that contains a Title (fixed at the top), body (scrollable) and Close button (fixed at the bottom).

I managed to get the body and button to work, but when i add the title section, it stops working and i keep getting
"java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ScrollView"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/detailDialogButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:text="Close"
        android:textSize="16dip" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailsDialogTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TEST TEST"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/detailsDialogSV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/detailDialogButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailsDialogTitle"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailsDialogText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp" >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Working now!

Comment: In your log cat what line in your code is the ClassCastException pointing to? Can you edit that line with a comment to indicate it for us?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that in your Java code you are trying to cast something that is a non-ScrollView to ScrollView or vice versa.

Can't know for sure though unless you edit your post and add the java code where you are calling findViewById();

Comment: Added the javacode as requested. That is all java code, only left out the imports.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid Eclipse that somehow saved old data and after a clean it worked